# Is "WorkingHours" element mandatory in "GetUserAvailabilityResponse"?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is this element mandatory when sending "GetUserAvailabilityResponse" to exchange server? If no, when should this element be sent?

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563496(v=exchg.150).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa565001(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Is this element mandatory when sending "GetUserAvailabilityResponse" to exchange server? If no, when should this element be sent?

GetUserAvailabilityResponse is the response that the Exchange Server will return in response to GetUserAvailabilityRequest 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563800(v=exchg.150).aspx

So its unclear as to what your question is as you would never send this yourself (the timezone is however a critical part of the request), workhours should be returned in the response if it has been set but you can't control whether it is or isn't returned.